# How to get itune link of our own application?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I am new to iphone development .I am in to project where application iTunes should be able to share on Facebook,twitter.I want to know how to obtain the iTunes link of the application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Login to itunesconnet accoumnt there just create a application here you can find the app link

Comment: cant we get it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iTunes link needs your app id from iTunes connect. There is no way for your application to actually know that number. 
However the app does not need to be released already to get the link, only to be created in iTunes Connect. That way you can still implement sharing functionality within your app using the link, and only then upload your binary.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You should give the link manually to the app or you should program the app to get the link from your own web server using web service. Here also you should update the link in you web server

Answer (score 0):

As everyone suggested, you need to create your app within iTunes Connect to get the App ID.

Once you have this, you can hardcode it into your app. An alternate way is to query your own server and have this information ready at the time the app is launched.

I would really suggest going for the hardcode method since the App ID doesn't ever change once it is assigned to your app.

Here's an example of how I usually embed the URL for my apps with its App ID: http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=APP_ID&mt=8&partnerId=30